# I can't make windows phone's context menu appear middle of screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu

I tried to show context menu by set field IsOpen, it's shown but its position is at top of screen, I wanna set it to show at middle, how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try setting the VerticalOffset property against the ContextMenu, as detailed in the following :-

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API

Comment: Ok, it's work but when I try to get height of context menu by field Height, a wrong argument problem occur when set field IsOpen.

It is able to get context menu's height by field Height right ?